# Does this make sense when linear regression results are out of the -1/+1 bandwidth?

Tags: regression, stata

I've computed a regression on panel data using the `xtreg` command in stata. 
My coefficients on some of the independent variables (which are binary-variables) are out of the range of -1 +1, even though the dependent variable is log transformed.

I find this rather odd, since a result of -2,3 would mean -230%, this doesn't seem possible with purely positive data.

Anyone has any idea how to interpret this, or what mistake I could have made?

Comment: It's possible, also are you sure the coefficient means a decrease of 230% or 2.3%?

Comment: im quite sure that the coefficient means a decrease of 230%, as I am using a log transformed dependent variable and there is no continuous independent variable - but of course, I am not certain.

Comment: @Andy W I thought if I switch the reference with the included binary it will probably turn around the result, to a positive number, showing the increase between the "before reference" to the "before independent". however I am not quite sure if its not too easy just to interpret the coefficient as an percental change, I should probably look into the formulas again - any ideas, whether this interpreation makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

> I find this rather odd, since a result of -2,3 would mean -230%, this
>   doesnt seem possible with purely positive data.

This is a commonly used rule-of-thumb interpretation used in linear regression models where the dependent variable is logarithmic (Some people call this a "semi-logarithmic" regression model). It gives acceptable results if the coefficient is close to zero. In your situation such an interpretation is more than problematic.

Call the coefficient of the dummy variable b and denote its variance V(b). Then, in a linear regression model with a logarithmic dependent variable, a coefficient of size b means that if the dummy switches from 0 to 1, the dependent variable increases by 100 * (exp(b - 0.5*V(b)) - 1) percent, ceteris paribus.

For more details, have a look at the following article:

Kees van Garderen and Chandra Shah, (2002). Exact interpretation of dummy variables in semilogarithmic equations. The Econometrics Journal, Vol. 5, No. 1, pp. 149-159.

Answer (score -1):

Since your independent variables are binary, try using [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Comment: I think you mean dependent variable.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Logit/probit are used when the DEPENDENT (left hand side) variable is binary.  The question is about binary right hand side variales.